# stack multiple PDF pages

Tags: overlays, stack

I have two PDF files, a form page with header and footer and a content page, and like to merge (overlay) them into a single page. Both PDFs are full size A4 portrait pages. I've tried this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[]{form.pdf}
\includepdf[]{content.pdf}
\end{document}
```

but this of course results in PDF file with two pages. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! (and StackPDF.SX! ;-) As far as I know, `\includepdf` will always ship out a new page for a new file!

Comment: It might be a little ugly, but you could try using the `viewport` option of `\includegraphics` from the `graphicx` package.

Comment: You could set one as the background using something like `background` or `wallpaper`. This obviously requires that at least one of the PDFs have a transparent background so that overlaying the other doesn't just block the other.

Comment: You should also be aware, that the form functionalities won't be preserved! It's included *flat*

Comment: There is an undocumented feature of \includegraphics[page=] which together with \raisebox will allow you to overlap them, but again you would first have to make one of them transparent.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'm a TeX Beginner so maybe someone could post a small example?

Comment: A solution that will always work is to put `tikz` nodes containing cropped (`standalone`) graphics in the same position in the `tikzpicture`. You can stretch them to fit your page.

Comment: @Lars: There are a dozen possibilities to overprint to images, but your solution is pretty clever! Please move it from the question into a dedicated answer, so that the question remains not unanswered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this is good style but it seems to work:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages,picture}
\usepackage{textpos}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[picturecommand={
  \includegraphics[]{content.pdf}
}]{form.pdf}
\end{document}
```

'form.pdf' is the backround and 'content.pdf' the overlaying content which has to have a transparent background.